# How to split a string between commas, one or more spaces and between digits and letters but not between dots with regex in java?

Tags: java, regex, split

As the title says I like to split a String between commas, one or more spaces and between digits and letters but not between dots with regex in java?

So for eample if I have the following String

```
"ab,cd76253  eruizgbe 19.05.1976, eribfuer243 fg"
```

I want to have an Array like this:

```
{"ab","cd","76253","eruizgbe","19.05.1976","eribfuer","243","fg"}
```

I have the following:

```
"ab,cd76253  eruizgbe 19.05.1976, eribfuer243 fg".split("[\\s,]+|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(? 
<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
```

But this also splits the the date between digits and dots.
How can I prevent to split between the digits and dots?

Comment: Use `[^\d.]` instead of `\D` like so:  `[\s,]+|(?<=[^\d.])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\d.])`

Comment: I did like this,  "[\\s,]+|(?<=^\\d.)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=^\\d.)" with "\\" before the d, otherwise compiler complains about escape character. But this is not splitting between "cd76253" for example

Comment: I wrote regex without escapement, to avoid confusion. In my answer you could see example of code with escapement in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[^\d.]` instead of `\D` to exclude digits and dots.

Also I've added `\s,` to negation, to exclude double split between space (or comma) and digits: `[\s,]+|(?<=[^\d\s.,])(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=[^\d\s.,])`

```java
for (String s : "ab,cd76253  eruizgbe 19.05.1976, eribfuer243 fg"
  .split("[\\s,]+|(?<=[^\\d.\\s,])(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=[^\\d.\\s,])")){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Output:

```
ab
cd
76253
eruizgbe
19.05.1976
eribfuer
243
fg
```

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OKu32h/2)

Comment: Sometimes this gives an empty String as output in between. For this for example "abc,12345" it gives "abc","","12345"

Comment: @midi, corrected. Needed also to add commas inside negative class.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you wish to break a string into pieces, discarding certain characters between pieces in the process, you should ask yourself whether it would be easier to split the string on substrings or match substrings.

In the example you wish to end up with the array

```
{"ab", "cd", "76253", "eruizgbe", "19.05.1976", "eribfuer", "243", "fg"}
```

This looks like you want pieces that are comprised of lowercase letters, digits or digits and periods, the last beginning and ending with a digit with no period followed by a period. If so, I suggest that you match the following regular expression.

```
[a-z]+|\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jBKQyk/1).

This expression reads, "match one or more (`+`) lowercase letters (`[a-z]`) or (`|`) one or more digits (`\d+`) followed by zero or more (`*`) strings comprised of a period followed by one or more digits".

---

Depending on requirements, some modifications may be necessary to the above expression.

If, for example, uppercase letters were to be permitted, it would be necessary to change `[a-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]` or to set the *case indifferent flag*. If other characters were permitted to be alongside letters one might even write

```
[^\d\s.]+|\d+(?:\.\d+)*
```

where the character class `[^\d\s.]` matches any one character other than (`^` at the beginning) a digit, a whitespace character (`\s`) or a period. The following `+` means to match one or more such characters.

---

To instead split the string on substrings one would need to employ a more complex regular expression.

One consideration when splitting strings is the possibility that the regular expression matches one or more characters at the beginning of the string, resulting in the first element of the array produced being an empty string. This could happen, for example, if a space were inserted at the beginning of the example string. The empty string could be avoided by modifying the regular expression, but that would cause the first string in the resulting array to begin with a space, which may not be desired. (Another possibility would be to pre-process the string in some way.) This is not an issue, of course, when matching substrings.

Sometimes spitting is best; other times matching is preferred.